# How to update MS word at node level(xml format) using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, doc

is it possible to get/set the native xml nodes directly as we can see of we set the '.docx' extension of ms word format to '.xml' extension using Apache POI? 
I've a use case where i need to update such attributes of some xml nodes(for both doc and docx extensions).
Or can anyone suggest some other helpful projects?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Flat OPC XML" format?  docx4j can import files in this format, you can edit the content (ie as a docx file), then you can save as docx or export back to "Flat OPC XML" format.

Comment: Naah... It was not possible for the use case i needed... Thought it was solved with apache poi itself, i tried that... See the updated answer in this post itself, thanx though :)

Answer (score -1):

Apache poi has a method getDomNode.
Full chain call is document.getDocument().getBody().getgetDomNode()
Any such xml level nodes are now accessible further
Sorry.. Took alot of POC, comparing with office openxml dtd blah blah..